# How to pass :current_user in Graphql resolver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, graphql, graphql-ruby

I have QueryType

```
Types::QueryType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name 'Query'

  field :allProjects, function: Resolvers::Projects
end
```

And Resolver like this

```
require 'search_object/plugin/graphql'

module Resolvers
  class Projects
    include SearchObject.module(:graphql)

    type !types[Types::ProjectType]

    scope { Project.all }

    ProjectFilter = GraphQL::InputObjectType.define do
      name 'ProjectFilter'

      argument :OR, -> { types[ProjectFilter] }
      argument :description_contains, types.String
      argument :title_contains, types.String
    end

    option :filter, type: ProjectFilter, with: :apply_filter
    option :first, type: types.Int, with: :apply_first
    option :skip, type: types.Int, with: :apply_skip

    def apply_first(scope, value)
      scope.limit(value)
    end

    def apply_skip(scope, value)
      scope.offset(value)
    end

    def apply_filter(scope, value)
      branches = normalize_filters(value).reduce { |a, b| a.or(b) }
      scope.merge branches
    end

    def normalize_filters(value, branches = [])
      scope = Project.all
      scope = scope.where('description ILIKE ?', "%#{value['description_contains']}%") if value['description_contains']
      scope = scope.where('title ILIKE ?', "%#{value['title_contains']}%") if value['title_contains']
      branches << scope

      value['OR'].reduce(branches) { |s, v| normalize_filters(v, s) } if value['OR'].present?
      branches
    end
  end
end
```

I want to access current_user in the resolver so i can access current_user.projects not Project.all.  I am very new to graphql and learning.

Everything works but i just need to understand the whole flow on how i can get old of the ctx in the resolver.

Comment: Do you use anything authentification or authorization related?

Comment: Yes. I use Knock gem

Comment: @suyesh Did you find out how to do that? Use `current_user` in the resolver?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you need to set the `current_user` in the context. This happens in your GraphqlController.

```rb
class GraphqlController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def execute
    variables = ensure_hash(params[:variables])
    query = params[:query]
    operation_name = params[:operationName]
    context = {
      current_user: current_user,
    }
    result = HabitTrackerSchema.execute(query, variables: variables, context: context, operation_name: operation_name)
    render json: result
  rescue => e
    raise e unless Rails.env.development?
    handle_error_in_development e
  end

  # ...
end
```

Once it's done, you can access the `current_user` from a query (or a mutation) simply by writing:

```rb
context[:current_user]
```

To make things even simpler, you can add a `current_user` method to`Types::BaseObject` (`app/graphql/types/base_object.rb`) and you'll be able to call `current_user` from the `#resolve` methods.

```rb
module Types
  class BaseObject < GraphQL::Schema::Object
    field_class Types::BaseField

    def current_user
      context[:current_user]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the best example to handle graphql to all the request

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: was very helpful how you showed a good place to put the helper method inside of `Types::BaseObject`. I was wondering where the best place for this would be